# Spark parquet row group size for wide tables

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hadoop2, parquet

I use Spark 1.6.0 to write a wide table (400+ columns) as a parquet file.
The resources of my executors is limited to 16Gb.

I read the table with `distribute by <partition_cols>` and then use `df.write.distributeBy(<partition_cols>).parquet(<path>)`.
This gives me one parquet file per partition. Thats exactly what I want.

The problem is, that the executors run out of memory when the partition size gets too big. I tried to address this problem, by reducing the `parquet.block.size`from 128Mb to 64Mb. This had no effect. When I examined an output parquet file, I saw that the row group size is only about 2Mb. 
For another parquet file, that was created from a narrow table with the same configuration, the row group size is 100Mb.

Can somebody explain to me how parquet files are written, and the effect of the `parquet.block.size`?

Thanks!